# flash - rescale an asset that's a hierarchy of bitmaps?

Tags: flash, bitmap, scale, assets, fla

I have some FLA/SWF assets which are hierarchies of bitmaps.
They have timelines which page-flip through different bitmaps.

I'd like to scale these assets down in pixel-size, including the bitmaps they're composed of.
I'm not a Flash Animator, but the artist i'm working with doesn't know of an automated way to achieve this. ie, that it's a long a laborious manual process.

Which is sort of a bummer.

Does anyone know of a tool which can simplify the re-scaling of bitmap-based FLAs ?

tia,
orion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the JSFL scripting language to traverse your FLA file and make changes to all the Bitmaps it can find.  JSFL is used all the time to do automated batch changes to huge numbers of FLA files.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/flash_cs3_extending.pdf

This does mean you need a developer who is familiar with JSFL and has the time to write the function you need.  JSFL is rather obscure, though, so finding someone who knows it is rough.  It's easier to find an enterprising dev on your team who is very good with ActionScript and JavaScript and then see if he's game for a challenge.